# FilePicker Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot copy file to 'Directory:

Tags: flutter, file, dart, mp3, filepicker

```
   `    onPressed: () async {

            FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();


            if (result != null) {
              File file = File(result.files.single.path.toString());
            } else {
              // User canceled the picker
            }



            if (result != null) {
              PlatformFile file = result.files.first;
              print('222222222222222222222222221');
              print(file.name);
              print("5555555555555555555555555555555");
              print(file.bytes);
              print(file.size);
              print(file.extension);
              print("6666666666666666666666666");
              print(file.path);
              final newFile = await saveFilePermanently(file);
            } else {
              // User canceled the picker
            }

          },    `      

  




`    Future<File> saveFilePermanently(PlatformFile file) async{
final appStorage = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final newFile = File('${appStorage}/${file.name}');
return File(file.path!).copy(newFile.path);
```

}    `

i got this error

E/flutter (  833): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot copy file to 'Directory: '/data/user/0/com.sangvaleap.online_course/app_flutter'/X2Download.com - Imagine Dragons x J.I.D - Enemy (from the series Arcane League of Legends) (128 kbps).mp3', path = '/data/user/0/com.sangvaleap.online_course/cache/file_picker/X2Download.com - Imagine Dragons x J.I.D - Enemy (from the series Arcane League of Legends) (128 kbps).mp3' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Comment: It states that it can't find the file or directory. Did you check the paths/files exist and maybe you need to check for read permission too

Comment: yes i added the permission ' <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>'   and the file exist